# Why the program without 'volatile' works as 'volatile'?

Tags: java, volatile, non-volatile

As typed below, the program has a shared var `flag` without `volatile`:

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TT jump = new TT(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if (TT.flag) {
                    System.out.println("jump");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        jump.start();
        new TT(() -> {
            TT.flag = true; // P1
            LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.now();
            while (true) {
                if (Duration.between(t1, LocalDateTime.now()).toMillis() > 100) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("flag");
        }).start();

    }

    static class TT extends Thread {
        public static boolean flag = false;
        public TT(Runnable o) {
            super(o);
        }
    }
}
```

The program always returns normally. So I believe the line of `P1` ,where the `flag` was set to `true`, updated `flag` in other threads.

But why? `flag` is not volatile, why its value was updated immediately? Always!

Comment: "Always" unless you have tested this on all compliant JVMs, you can't make that statement. The JVM(s) that you are trying it on might just happen to be implemented so this *happens* to be true.

Comment: Btw, [it times out on Ideone](http://ideone.com/ilxUBE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why? flag is not volatile, why its value was updated immediately? Always!

You are simply lucky; or unlucky, depending upon your perspective. I tried this on Ideone, and found that it timed out rather than terminating normally.

Remember: not being able to observe a concurrency bug is not the same as an absence of a concurrency bug.

The most sure you can be about code is when you can prove, according to the specification, that there are no bugs. That doesn't mean that the code will then work correctly; it just means that the problems are in the JVM implementation.

In particulary, you can't prove that this code will work correctly, because there is no *happens-before* relationship between the write to `flag` in the second thread, and the read in the first thread. Adding `volatile` creates this guarantee, because a volatile write happens before a volatile read.

That's not to say it will *never* work without volatile, it's just not guaranteed: a JVM only has to flush a thread's cached values at least as often as the spec requires, but can do it more often, or indeed not cache values at all.